# How to get the sql output using Splunk DB connect for 2 DBs?

Tags: connection-string, splunk, splunk-dbconnect

Getting the payment details from 1 DB and using those values in 2nd DB to get the results. But as per SQL limit payment ID IN (<limited to 999 payment ids from 1st DB>). How do we do this using **SPLUNK DB CONNECT** which allows more than 30K payment IDs? I have both DBs connection strings.

1st sql with connection:

```
| streamstats count as "rc" 
| table payment_id rc 
| eval rc1 = rc%10 
| table payment_id rc1 
| eval payment_id = "'"+payment_id+"'," 
| stats values(payment_id) as payment_id by rc1 
| mvcombine delim="" payment_id 
| nomv payment_id 
| rex field=payment_id "(?<payment_id>.*)." 
| map search="|dbxquery connection = ""
```

<2nd sql here where using the above payment_id in where condition as below>

```
(payment_id IN ("$payment_id$"))>
```

Here it will divide the no of payment_id values by 10 and send the streams to map. As MAP only allows 9 values, I have to divide it by 10. Example: if I have 9K payment ids, 9K%10 streams will be formed and send to 2nd sql query. Here the limitation is only for 10K records only the below will work. it won't work for more than 10K payment_ids

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: 1st sql with connection | streamstats count as "rc" | table payment_id rc | eval rc1 = rc%10 | table payment_id rc1 | eval payment_id = "'"+payment_id+"'," | stats values(payment_id) as payment_id by rc1 | mvcombine delim="" payment_id | nomv payment_id | rex field=payment_id "(?<payment_id>.*)." |map search="|dbxquery connection = "" <2nd sql here where using the above payment_id in where condition as below>

(payment_id IN ("$payment_id$"))>

Comment: here it will divide the no of payment_id values by 10 and send the streams to map. As MAP only allows 9 values, i have to divide it by 10. Example: if i have 9K payment ids, 9K%10 streams will be formed and send to 2nd sql query.

Here the limitation is only for 10K records only the below will work. it won't work for more than 10K payment_ids.

Comment: I've edited your comments into the question so they're readable

Answer (score 0):

```
1st sql with connection
| streamstats count as "rc"
| table payment_id rc
| eval rc1 = rc%10
| table payment_id rc1
| eval payment_id = "'"+payment_id+"',"
| stats values(payment_id) as payment_id by rc1 
| mvcombine delim="" payment_id | nomv payment_id
| rex field=payment_id "(?<payment_id>.*)."
| map search="|dbxquery connection = "" <2nd sql here where using the above payment_id in where condition as below>
```

**(payment_id IN ("$payment_id$"))**>

---

Here it will divide the no of payment_id values by 10 and send the streams to map. As MAP only allows 9 values, I have to divide it by 10. Example: if I have 9K payment ids, 9K%10 streams will be formed and sent to the 2nd sql query.

Here the limitation is only for 10K records only the below will work. It won't work for more than 10K `payment_ids`.